# Как задать высоту изображения одинаковую?

Tags: html, height

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

подскажите пожалуйста, столкнулся с такой проблемой...
Делал верстку страницы, у постов все изображения в верстке имеют стандартную высоту и ширину 235px и 555px соответственно. При адаптиве для планшетов и мобильников, изображения уменьшаются, все ок, но если загрузить изображение с большей или меньшей высотой, то все "едет", можно ли как-то зафиксировать высоту, чтобы она сама подстраивалась, как если бы загружались изображения только с одной высотой ? попробовал overflow:hidden, помогло только с фиксированной высотой, дальше, при уменьшении страницы, изображение с "нестандартной" высотой кривое (на изображении у пиццы высота больше)

```
      <div class="excursions__item">
        <div class="excursions__img">
          <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <img src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>" alt="Фото Mercedes">
          </a>
        </div>
        <h3 class="excursions__title"> <?php the_title(); ?> </h3>
        <div class="excursions__text">
          <?php the_content(); ?>
        </div>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"
          class="btn excursions__button"><?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'excursion_button', true); ?></a>
      </div>
```

```
.excursions {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
  
  }
  
  .excursions__item {
    margin-bottom: 42px;
    max-width: 47%;
    text-align: center;
    
  }
  
  .excursions__img {
    margin-bottom: 23px;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-height: 235px;
  }
  
  .excursions__img img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  
  }
  
  .excursions__img a {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
  }
```

Comment: `max-height: 235px;` заменить на `height: 235px;`?

Comment: не помогает, дальше, когда страницу уменьшаю, высота у изображений "новых", отличных от верстки больше

Comment: на версии на пк в моем коде все ок, потом начинаю разрешение уменьшать, все картинки с размером 555 на 235, с ними все ок, они уменьшаются равномерно, а "новую" картинку, которую добавил, у нее с шириной все ок, а с высотой нет, она автоматически не уменьшается, неужели нужно media=запросы каждые 5 пикселей делать, уменьшая высоту, чтобы все равномерно было, это же бред...

Comment: ну подскажите, кто-нибудь... до сих пор не пойму как сделать, туплю...